# Format string using RegEx

Tags: c#

String to be formatted

"new Date(2009,0,1)"

String after formatting

"'01-Jan-2009'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `DateTime` structure:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(something);
string str = date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

In your case, you should use a regular expression to parse the values out of the string, like this:

```
static readonly Regex parser = new Regex(@"new Date\((\d{4}),\s*(\d\d?),\s*(\d\d?)\)");

Match match = parser.Match("new Date(2009,0,1)");

DateTime date = new DateTime(
    int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value),
    int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value) + 1,
    int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value)
);

string str = date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

(Tested)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a regex for this - you can only work with existing text. Adding new characters (Jan instead of 1 (or 0??)) is not possible.

What you can do is match `@"new Date\((\d+),(\+d),(\d+)\)`. Then you'll have three strings containing `2009`, `0`, and `1` in the Match object's groups 1, 2, and 3.